# Do I need to call Graphics.Dispose()?

Tags: .net, dispose

In a VB.NET program I'm creating a new bitmap image, I then call Graphics.FromImage to get a Graphics object to draw on the bitmap. The image is then displayed to the user.

All the code samples I've seen always call .Dispose() on Bitmaps and Graphics objects, but is there any need to do that when neither have touched files on disk? Are there any other unmanaged resources that these objects might have grabbed that wouldn't be cleared by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Always call `Dispose()` on any object that implements `IDisposable`. GDI handles used by graphics objects are unmanaged and require disposing when you are finished with them.

Best practice is to wrap in a `using` block. There have been several SO questions on this topic, BTW.

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate. I didn't see anything that related to this specific case and was curious what (if any) unmanaged resources would be used in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap it in a **using statement** for the scope in which you need it.  Then don't worry about explicitly calling Dispose()

Pseudocode:

```
using(new Graphics() = Graphics.FromImage)
{
     //Magic happens...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should call Dispose. It is not related to touching the disk; it is related to using unmanaged resources that need to be released properly back to the operating system. In the case of the `Graphics` object, I would assume that it allocates device context handles that should be released when they are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The rule with `Dispose()` is that if you created an object that is `IDisposable`, then you are supposed to call it.  The best way is within a `using` block or a `finally`.

It might be that you didn't need to do it, but Dispose() will decide that.

If you got an object, but didn't call the constructor, then you need to check the documentation for the method that returned it to see if it expects you to call Dispose() or it will.

Comment: To be precise, proper use of `using` (see other answers) implicitly does `Dispose`, so you don't need to call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[Graphics implements IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx), so you should call Dispose to ensure clean up of unmanaged resources.

Unmanaged resources are not handled by the garbage collector, so they must be handled manually. This is typically done by the Dispose() method in order to provide cleanup at a well defined point in time. It may also be handled by a finalizer but in that case the resource(s) will be in use longer than necessary.

The easiest way to ensure that Dispose is called in all cases is to employ the using construct. E.g.

```
using(var g = Graphics.FromImage()) {
    // use the resource 
}
```

Comment: "they must be handled manually" is not strictly true as you wrote a bit later. Proper implementation of `IDisposable` should make sure you'll be safe even without manual (in your code) disposing.

Comment: @MaciejDopieralski: I would consider anything you have to write code for to be a manual process. If you forget to call Dispose clean up will not take place. Collection of managed objects on the other hand happens automatically.

Comment: If you're talking about own classes then yes but all .NET framework `IDisposable` classes get disposed sooner or later even if you do not call `Dispose` in your code.

Comment: @MaciejDopieralski: Nothing gets disposed simply by implementing `IDisposable`. You need to call `Dispose` either explicitly or via the `using` construct. Now, if the type also implements a finalizer that may call `Dispose` for you, but that doesn't change the fact that this is something the developer must handle, which makes it different from the automatic clean up of managed memory handled by the GC.

Comment: I know all that. I guess it's semantics. To me .NET libraries and .NET runtime are just The Framework. All standard framework classes follow proper `IDisposable` pattern thus get disposed automatically if I don't do it by myself (which I know I should)

Comment: FWIW, the confusion in the above back-and-forth starts with Brian not distinguishing *what must be done by the designer of a class that handles unmanaged resources* -- the second paragraph "Unmanaged resources ..., from what *a client of that class needs to do* -- "ensure that Dispose is called".

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - Calling Dispose is a good idea as it deterministically releases the unmanaged resources; however the Finalizer should properly implement the IDisposable pattern so that if one does not call Dispose explicitily (the using statement being syntactic sugare)... Bottom line, for well designed classes the Dispose menthod will be called during Garbage Collection (Eventually)